# Concurrency in Mono Wcf project

Tags: c#, wcf, mono, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service which uses `NetTcpBinding`.
I need only one thread in my service, so I set `InstanceContextMode` to `Single` and `ConcurrencyMode` to `Single`.
When I run my service on `Windows OS`, it works how it should be. I wrote a small example to demonstrate this:

```
03.04.2018 15:56:30: Service started
03.04.2018 15:56:34: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:56:34: I'm done!
03.04.2018 15:56:35: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:56:35: I'm done!
03.04.2018 15:56:36: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:56:36: I'm done!
03.04.2018 15:56:37: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:56:37: I'm done!
```

As you see, each other call waits for previous call to finish. But when I run the same service with the same settings on `Linux`, it works incorrectly. Like this:

```
03.04.2018 15:59:22: Service started
03.04.2018 15:59:27: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:59:28: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:59:28: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:59:28: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:59:28: I'm done!
03.04.2018 15:59:29: I'm done!
03.04.2018 15:59:29: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:59:29: I'm starting work!
03.04.2018 15:59:29: I'm done!
03.04.2018 15:59:29: I'm starting work!
```

Here you can see that all calls are being executed simultaneously and concurrency settings are not working properly.

Is this a bug in WCF implementation in Mono? Or how can I make this work correctly?

Comment: How do you run  the service on Linux ?

Comment: You're lucky. I'm trying to use a BasicHttpBinding with InstanceMode=PerCall and ConcurrencyMode=Multiple, and I can't get the thing to operate in anything but a Single threaded way.

I've surmised that when a request is done, it issues a WaitHandle.Set on a semaphore which seems to release a Thread Pool Worker to work on the next request. However, this WaitHandle.Set should be done immeidately.